# How can I add more than one font family in html tag in mpdf

Tags: html, fonts, dompdf, mpdf, font-family

I am using mpdf to generate a report. In that report I have to display malayalam, tamil kannada etc etc languages. These comes in name field. I want to add more than one font family to that field tag. Now its code is
 `$html.='<td><font style="font-family:ind_ml_1_001;" size="50">'.$rows['namemal'].'</font></td>';` 
here what i want is to add more fonts family. I have tried 
 `$html.='<td><font style="font-family:ind_ml_1_001,ind_ta_1_001,ind_kn_1_001;" size="50">'.$rows['namemal'].'</font></td>';` 
 But its not working it takes only first font family. Plz somebody help me...

Comment: have you loaded fonts `ind_ml_1_001,ind_ta_1_001,ind_kn_1_001` in CSS??

Comment: yes, im getting all these individually

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to specify more than one font for a particular container tag using HTML+CSS. You have three options:

1) Find a Unicode font that supports all the character sets you need to represent. I recommend you go this route.

2) Record the necessary language/character set information with the user record. Then set the font styling dynamically based on that information. Something like this:

```
switch ($rows['lang']) {
  case 'tamil kannada':
    $font = 'ind_ta_1_001';
    break;
  default:
    $font = 'ind_ml_1_001';
}
$html.='<td><font style="font-family:' . $font . '"size="50">'.$rows['namemal'].'</font></td>';
```

That, of course, requires you to record the font information with each record.

3) You could *try* to determine the correct font based on the characters used. But that's not really practical since you would have to parse each character and compare it against a library of characters for the target languages.